# Update more than one row in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to update the table values by using hard coded values.here is my code :

```
BEGIN

  UPDATE emp_table  
     SET expiry_dt = TO_DATE('21.09.2009:00:00:01','DD.MM.YYYY:HH24:MI:SS'),
   WHERE emp_id = '78629160';

  UPDATE emp_table  
     SET expiry_dt = TO_DATE('21.09.2009:00:00:01','DD.MM.YYYY:HH24:MI:SS'),
   WHERE emp_id = '78629160';

END
```

I want to do it in the single update statement.  Can anyone tell me the solution?

Comment: Can you clarify?  Are you trying to update multiple columns for a single emp_id or a single column for multiple emp_ids?  In your example, the UPDATE statements are identical.

Comment: I don't get it - why would you want to update the same row the same way twice?

Comment: @nonnb, so that it *stays* updated, of course :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   UPDATE emp_table  SET expiry_dt = TO_DATE 
   ('21.09.2009:00:00:01','DD.MM.YYYY:HH24:MI:SS'),
    WHERE emp_id IN ('78629160','111020102','88888888');
```

Should do you. Edited the IN clause with various employee id's as yours were identical.

Answer (score 2):

```
 UPDATE emp_table  
   SET expiry_dt = 
     CASE 
       WHEN emp_id = '78629160' THEN TO_DATE('21.09.2009:00:00:01','DD.MM.YYYY:HH24:MI:SS')
       WHEN emp_id = '78629161' THEN TO_DATE('21.10.2009:00:00:01','DD.MM.YYYY:HH24:MI:SS')
     END
 WHERE emp_id IN ('78629160', '78629161')
```

I assume the fact that you have the same ID twice was just a copy and paste error, just like the fact that both dates are identical.

Btw: what data type is `emp_id`? If that is a numeric type, get rid of the single quotes for the literals (numeric literals should not be quoted). They will prevent the usage of an index on that column!

Comment: Why have your suggested the CASE statement?

Comment: My interpretation of the question was that the OP wants to update two rows with different ids to a different date value for each row in just a single statement. Maybe that understanding was wrong

Answer (score 0):

Begin    UPDATE emp_table  SET expiry_dt = TO_DATE     ('21.09.2009:00:00:01','DD.MM.YYYY:HH24:MI:SS'),-- why you are using ',' here??
WHERE emp_id = '78629160';

Begin
UPDATE emp_table  SET expiry_dt = TO_DATE('21.09.2009:00:00:01','DD.MM.YYYY:HH24:MI:SS')
WHERE emp_id = '78629160'; 
end;

It is running in my machine whithout any error and problem.. adn giving expected result also..
try once again without using that ','.

Comment: I suspect he's redacted multiple columns being set in the update statement, and forgotten to omit the comma.